# OAuth Redirect Url inconsistency

Tags: google-apps-script

We run into a problem with the redirect url
In the [doc](https://developers.google.com/gmail/add-ons/how-tos/non-google-services#using_an_oauth_service)

it specifies you should set your redirect url to
`https://script.google.com/macros/d/<Apps Script ID>/usercallback`

However when we did that the redirect url doesn't actually contain our app script ID, it's something totally different

We managed to copy the actual redirect url sent to our server and get it to proceed but is there a bug I wonder

Comment: Where did you get the script ID? Did you copy it from the editor URL or did you open the project properties and copy the script ID string from there? They're different and if you use the editor URL, your call will fail.

Comment: Thanks Brian, I copied the Deployment id from the Public -> Deploy by Manifest window, I thought they the deployment ID and the script ID were the same thing, anyway I will use the script ID like you suggested now, thank